# JProfiler with ArangoDB

Tags: jprofiler

Curretly JProfiler supports the following Databases :
JDBC , JPA/Hibernet , MongoDB , Cassandra , HBase .
I am trying to use Jprofiler for ArangoDB profiling . How to configure JProfiler for ArangoDB Profiling?

Answer (score 0):

As of 11.0, there is no support for ArangoDB in JProfiler. JProfiler has an API for writing your own probes.

If you can modify of subclass the ArangoDB driver code, write an [embedded probe](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.customProbes.embeddedProbes), if not, write an [injected probe](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.customProbes.injectedProbes).

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use injected probe . Can I get some guidance how to profile ArangoDB using injected probe .

Comment: The `api/samples/simple-injected-probe` and `api/samples/advanced-injected-probe` directories in the JProfiler installation contain relevant samples. I cannot give any specific advice for ArangoDB.